# How to iterate rows of the first table in Cheerio?

Tags: cheerio

Lets say we have this simplified version of two tables:

```
<table class="test">
    <tr>some text</tr>
    <tr>another text</tr>
</table>

<table class="test">
    <tr>it's a text</tr>
    <tr>different text></tr>
</table>
```

How do I iterate through the `<tr>` elements of the FIRST `<table>` with `class="test"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('table.test').first().find('tr').each(function(i, tr){
  console.log($(tr).text())
})
```

If they're really right next to each other you could do:

```
$('table.test:nth-of-type(1) tr').each(function(i, tr){
  console.log($(tr).text())
})
```